# Javascript: Cannot read property 'style' of null on Else

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The error message: Cannot read property 'style' of null shows up on the first statement of my "else" statement.  Not sure where I am going wrong.  Any thoughts?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var foursquareApi = {
        clientId: "CLIENT_ID",
        clientSecret: "CLIENT_SECRET",
        redirectUrl: "http://almontas.github.io/FourSquareJax/"
    }

    if (access_token === 0) {

        document.getElementById('dashboardProfile').style.display == 'none';
        document.getElementById('dashboardInfo').style.display == 'none';

        $('.connect').click(function () {

            var url = "https://foursquare.com/oauth2/access_token";
            url += "?client_id=" + foursquareApi.clientId;
            url += "&response_type=token";
            url += "&redirect_uri=" + foursquareApi.redirectUrl;
            window.location = url;

        });
    } else {
        document.getElementById('dashboardProfile').style.display == 'block'; //this lines gives an error message. 
        document.getElementById('dashboardInfo').style.display == 'block';
    }
```

Here is some of the HTML in question.  The .dashboardProfile and .dashboardInfo seem to be in place as mentioned by comments.

```
<body>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="header">
            <div class="logo"><img src = "images/foursquare-logo.png"> 
            </div> 


       </div>

            <div class="dashboard-container">


            <div class="dashboardConnect">
                <div class="connect"><p> Sign In </p>
                </div>

           </div>

                <div class="dashboardProfile">
                    <p>User Information and Picture</p>     
                </div>

                <div class="dashboardInfo">
                    <p>Check Ins </p>   
                    <div class="indicator checkin"> # </div>

                    <p>Countries</p>   
                    <div class="indicator country"> # </div>

                    <p>Cities</p>   
                    <div class="indicator city"> # </div>


                </div>

           </div>   

    </div><!--container-fluid-->
```

Comment: Probably means that there's no element with the id "dashboardProfile".

Comment: Can you add your HTML?

Comment: FYI, you are misusing `==` in case of setting the property value. It is supposed to be a single `=` character.

Comment: Loading jQuery while using vanilla DOM?...

Comment: Nothing wrong with sprinkling a little vanilla in with the ol ``$``. There are bigger problems here ^^

Comment: @–  VisioN updated HTML

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have an element with the ID `dashboardProfile`, you have an element with the class `dashboardProfile`.

So you do:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('dashboardProfile')[0].style.display = "none"
```

Same goes for your other `document.getElementById`, you don't have any elements with IDs in your HTML.

Comment: Great one! I have a question. Why does the '[0]' needs to be added?

Comment: Because `document.getElementsByClassName` returns a collection of elements (sort of like an Array) and you want the first one (you only have one)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way with jquery it's easier

$('.dashboardProfile').css("display","block");
$('.dashboardInfo').css("display","block");

Answer (score 0):

**1) make sure you have a element with id `dashboardProfile` beacause you getting error like**

```
'Cannot read property 'style' of null'
```

**2) if you assign value to element you should use single `=`**

```
  document.getElementById('dashboardProfile').style.display = 'block';
```

== is  a  comparison operator so, you cannot assign value using ==

Comment: I personally don't understand your last statement.

Comment: The comparison operator`(==)` is used to compare two operands. It returns true or false based on comparison. The complete list of comparison operators are listed in a table.

Comment: I assume you mistyped: should be either `can't` or `using =`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access the property **style** of `dashboardProfile` if it is not present. Check its presence by :

```
if ( document.getElementById('dashboardProfile') !== null ) {
     document.getElementById('dashboardProfile').style.display = 'block';
}
```

Also , for assigning a value, use `=` and for comparison use `==` or `===`.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use `getElementById()` to find an element by its class name, and that simply does not work. It looks like you can just change the HTML:

```
            <div id="dashboardProfile">
                <p>User Information and Picture</p>     
            </div>

            <div id="dashboardInfo">
                <p>Check Ins </p>   
                ...
```

Also note the other answer: you're trying to update the style with the wrong JavaScript operator.